# Android drawerlayoyt sliding options

Tags: android, android-layout, drawerlayout

The default sliding menu transition is to slide over the main view.

Are they other options for the menu transition?
Like moving the main view with the swipe?
Or any other option?

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html, You can set a listener on the drawer:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener((DrawerLayout.DrawerListener) listener);
```

The listener implementation is defined here:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html

You can than implement

```
DrawerListener.onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
```

and than use slideOffset in order to animate other views, like moving the main view in relation to the slide offset.